# Unity v4 (for MVC 5) not resolving registered types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I've created interface, to separate controller from concrete implementation:

```
    private IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public AccountController(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }
```

And set up type registration:

```
        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
        // container.LoadConfiguration();

        **container.RegisterType<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();**
        // asp identity
        container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>, UserStoreIntPk>();
        container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>>();
        container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
        container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();
        container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(new InjectionFactory(o => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
    }
```

But my private variable _userRepository in controller is always null!
Why? How can I fix it?

**EDIT1: Global.asax:**

```
        protected void Application_Start()
    {


        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        //var factory = new CustomControllerFactory();
        //ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(factory);

        UnityWebActivator.Start();
    }
```

Comment: Please show your startup code where you wire in Unity.

Comment: it's in Global.asax
     protected void Application_Start()  


        {  
         ...
            UnityWebActivator.Start();  
        }
-- added to original question

Comment: What happens if you try to resolve `IUserRepository` just for the sake of testing?

Comment: At this line 'var result = container.Resolve(typeof(IUserRepository),"test");'. Following error occures: Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, Shared.Interfaces.IUserRepository, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Comment: And mappings are there of course.

Comment: This extension resolve-method worked. For testing only. 
var result = container.Resolve<IUserRepository>();

It does not happen automaticaly when controller is constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the causes of error. My controller had multiple constructors. And Unity selected constructors with maximum parameters (longest one). And it was not my constructor with my dependency parameter.

So, I adjusted initial constructor to take my additional parameter.

```
public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, IUserRepository userRepository)
```

And now everything works just fine.